# 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable error in KivyMD

Tags: python-3.x, kivymd

I'm new to KivyMD and I'm trying to make a simple app in PyCharm. But I get this TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable error everytime I run the code. I use python 3.8 and the latest KivyMD version. I've saw this error before but I couldn't solve it. Can you help me please? This is the code:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


Window.size = (300, 500)

Builder.load_string("""       
ScreenManager:
    Homepage:
    Profile_page:
    Settings_page:
           
            
<Homepage>:
    name: 'home'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDToolbar:
            title: "Home"
            left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state('toggle')]]
            elevation: 10
        
    MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer
            ScrollView:
                MDList:
                    OneLineIconListItem:
                        text: 'Home'
                        IconLeftWidget:
                            icon: 'home'
                    OneLineIconListItem:
                        text: 'Profile'
                        IconLeftWidget:
                            icon: 'face'
                    OneLineIconListItem:
                        text: 'Settings'
                        IconLeftWidget:
                            icon: 'wrench'
        
        
<Profile_page>:
    name: 'profile'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDToolbar:
            title: "Profile"
            left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state('toggle')]]
            elevation: 10
        
    MDNavigationDrawer:
        id: nav_drawer
        ScrollView:
            MDList:
                OneLineIconListItem:
                    text: 'Home'
                    IconLeftWidget:
                        icon: 'home'
                OneLineIconListItem:
                    text: 'Profile'
                    IconLeftWidget:
                        icon: 'face'
                OneLineIconListItem:
                    text: 'Settings'
                    IconLeftWidget:
                        icon: 'wrench'
        
        
<Settings_page>:
    name: 'settings'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDToolbar:
            title: "Settings"
            left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state('toggle')]]
            elevation: 10
        
    MDNavigationDrawer:
        id: nav_drawer
        ScrollView:
            MDList:
                OneLineIconListItem:
                    text: 'Home'
                    IconLeftWidget:
                        icon: 'home'
                OneLineIconListItem:
                    text: 'Profile'
                    IconLeftWidget:
                        icon: 'face'
                OneLineIconListItem:
                    text: 'Settings'
                    IconLeftWidget:
                        icon: 'wrench'
""")


class Profilepage(Screen):
    pass


class Homepage(Screen):
    pass


class Settingspage(Screen):
    pass


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(Profilepage(name='profile'))
        sm.add_widget(Homepage(name='home'))
        sm.add_widget(Settingspage(name='settings'))
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Red"

        return sm


MainApp().run()
```

And here is the error:

```
   File "Q:/Users/xiers/Desktop/python/App/main.py", line 12, in <module>
     Builder.load_string("""       
   File "Q:\Users\xiers\Desktop\python\App\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 373, in load_string
     parser = Parser(content=string, filename=fn)
   File "Q:\Users\xiers\Desktop\python\App\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 402, in __init__
     self.parse(content)
   File "Q:\Users\xiers\Desktop\python\App\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 511, in parse
     objects, remaining_lines = self.parse_level(0, lines)
   File "Q:\Users\xiers\Desktop\python\App\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 614, in parse_level
     _objects, _lines = self.parse_level(
   File "Q:\Users\xiers\Desktop\python\App\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 674, in parse_level
     if current_property[:3] == 'on_':
 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Something is wrong with that string you're passing in or this is a bug with the library.

Comment: @nlta I didn't understand what's the problem but when I wrote the code again in another file it worked. Anyways thanks for your reply!